# Multipage App whith angular and sql backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, yeoman

I'm designing a small app which would have a couple of independent pages. I'm planning to use angular for the front end and I need an SQL database on the backend.

I'm not really designing a web application, but a in-house systeme, using (cheap) mobile phone for operators tasks (a kind of todo list for each operator) and supervisor page on a desktop which is used to assigned tasks to operators.
There is at the moment 3 different pages:
1- the mobile todo list
2- the administrator scheduling page 
3- administrator report and stats.

Only the first one needs angular, the 2 other could be done as a standard web app, but I'll prefer to use angular if possible.

I'm thinking of either using Rails (only because I know it) to read/write from the database and export/import json to the angular pages. However it doesn't solve the problem of how to do a multiple pages angular application ? 
All the pages even though different angular "views" will probably share the same components.
I would like to avoid using angular routing because I'm using cheap and slow mobile for the todo-like, so I don't want it to be overloaded with things it doesn't need.

### Update

I'm also using yeoman, not sure is the best choice as it seems to manage single page application. 
Maybe I need to have one yeoman project per view ???

So what is the best practice to have a rail application to host different angular pages ?

Also if there is an easier way to serve sql directly to angular, I can use something different that rail.

Comment: why the downvote ? I think it's legitimate question

Answer (score 0):

In my Rails/Angular apps, I use $resource to RESTfully get/put data within the RoR created database. Here are the docs for $resource.

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

Here is an example how I did it in a resume web app i am building for myself.

```
app = angular.module("Resume", ["ngResource"])

app.factory "Entry", ["$resource", ($resource) ->
  $resource("/entries")
]

@EntryCtrl = ["$scope", "Entry", ($scope, Entry) ->
  $scope.entries = Entry.query()
  $scope.showThis = false

  $scope.isClass = (isProject) ->
    if isProject == true
      $scope.myVar = "project alert-info"
    else
      $scope.myVar = "tech alert-success"
]
```

*The coffeescript functions are in array's to protect them from compiling.

**This code is similar to how Ryan Bates examples at Railscasts.com

Comment: My question is more about how do you deal with the view ? Do you do an angular app per rails views or one rails view and different route in the angular app ?

Comment: What I posted is located in my app/assets/javascripts directory. For the views, I use $scope to call database entries into the normal rails view. I work the angular $scope vars into the HTML in the same way I would typically use ERB to call ruby vars.